# TDBOutput: Update super slow [Talend Open Studio]

Tags: ms-access-2010, talend, insert-update

My target is:

- Take a csv file
- compare to a DB access
- update the necessary row
- insert the necessary row

The logic of my Talend seems ok and working. But the Update process is super slow... Do you have any ideas how I can make it faster?

[Talend Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiEcR.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Add an index on the update key

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: as @IbrahimMezouar mentionned you could add an index on the update key . or try to use  partitions in your table

Answer (score 0):

I put an index (Yes No duplicate) on the update key in my access database.
I put a key on my mapping in talend.

Do you think it is the size of the Database?:

- 60000 rows
- 20 columns
- size : 20M

460s to updated 700row

My next try will be to try on a SQL Database.